# Tooltip covers the button so I get org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException

Tags: selenium

I'm using Selenium for integration testing of our web app, and it's been working great up until I got far enough down the sidebar menu. Suddently the Create test would fail with `org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted. Other element would receive the click:`

The error was very sporadic - order of tests would affect which test class failed - but finally I figured out the reason is that the tooltip from the most recently clicked menu option covers the button I'm trying to click. Not really sure why sending input to form elements (using `WebElement:sendKeys()` and `org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select`) does not count as moving the mouse away.

Is there a way to make Selenium work around this, or do we have to turn off tooltips in the test version (for obvious reasons I don't like the idea of running our tests on a custom version of the web app)?

Comment: it's quite hard to help without any screenshot, page source and etc...but in this case, I'd consider trying to implement a simple method that would check if the element/tooltip is visible and return it as Optional<WebElement> (I assume you're using Java)...if it's empty, continue with your click on the button, otherwise click on this element == the tooltip first

Comment: @Marek Yes, I'm using Java. The problem is that practically everything in the app has a tooltip, so that method would be pretty big. I found Actions:moveByOffset(), but it seems to move the mouse pointer off screen after enough calls resulting in `MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException`. What I'd like is either a `moveToPosition()` method or a `WebElement:isCovered()` method so the pointer only moves when it has to.

Comment: A bit ugly, but this seems to work:
`public static void clickButton(WebDriver driver, String buttonId) {`
`  try {`
`    new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(5)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id(buttonId))).click();`
`  } catch(Exception e) {`
`    new Actions(driver).moveByOffset(200, 0).perform();`
`    new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(5)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id(buttonId))).click();`
`  }`
`  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofMillis(1000));`
`}`

Comment: Use JSExecutor for the clicking.

Comment: A bit ugly, but this seems to work:
`public static void clickButton(WebDriver driver, String buttonId) {`
`try {`
`new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(5)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id(buttonId))).click();`
`} catch(Exception e) {`
`new Actions(driver).moveByOffset(200, 0).perform();`
`new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(5)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id(buttonId))).click();`
`}`
`driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofMillis(1000));`
`}`

Comment: as you already mentioned above, you can get MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException...and I'm afraid there's still a chance to get that exception, even if you move by 200

if it's possible, I'd still rather dismiss the tooltip first and only then proceed with the click on that requested button

it's up to you :)

Comment: For time being you can use the JavaScript executer. 
WebElement element = driver.findElement(elementToClick);
  JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
  executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
After that you can find the better solution for it

Comment: So that hops straight to the onclick() attribute of the element? Does it work if the element is hidden and not just covered by other elements?